# What is the semantic Bootstrap markup for yes/no radio buttons with a third 'question' label?

Tags: forms, accessibility, bootstrap-5, semantic-markup

Example of intended output:

**What is your answer to this form question?**

o YES

o NO

Both Yes and No are labels to their respective radio buttons, but the preceding text in bold is also semantically related to the buttons.

The Bootstrap examples do not refer to this.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
</div>
```

I am not using a checkbox as I want to force a response from the user.

Comment: This isn't a Bootstrap question, which is why the Bootstrap docs don't address it. It's fundamental to HTML.